# Best ANSI options when creating a new database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of creating a new database onto SQL Server 2012 for our production environment.  When I use the "New Database..." option from SQL Server Management Studio and generate the output I get:

```
CREATE DATABASE [AAA]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'AAA', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014\MSSQL\DATA\AAA.mdf' , SIZE = 5120KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'AAA_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014\MSSQL\DATA\AAA_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON(INCREMENTAL = OFF)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AAA] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO
USE [AAA]
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.filegroups WHERE is_default=1 AND name = N'PRIMARY') ALTER DATABASE [AAA] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] DEFAULT
GO
```

Why are so many ANSI options defaulting to OFF?
The server instance was set up by RackSpace on our behalf.  Could it be because of some defaults they set up in the instance?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Good Question. Each of these settings is pretty much a subject in itself. I don't think anybody could give you a great answer in the length limit of stack overflow. If there are any that you're concerned about I'd ask about them separately (after a google). One thing I do see is that your log file is set to grow by a percentage, if you can change this to a fixed amount it would probably be for the best.

Comment: Thanks @RichBenner for the info on auto-growing by a percentage.  The setting that most bothers me is `ANSI_NULLS`.  Standards tell me that `NULL=NULL` should return `UNKNOWN` / `NULL` (i.e. when option is ON) and not `TRUE` (when option is OFF), however the default appears to be the latter (OFF) and this site advises leaving it set to OFF: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-properties-health-check/

Comment: The advise at simple-talk is sound.  In general you don't want to create columns that allow nulls by default.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh, No, simple-talk advices to leave ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF , not ANSI_NULL. Although many software packages adhere to ANSI standard you need to check it with your packages manuals.

Comment: @MisterPositive: I'm not so worried about `ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT` as I always explicitly state whether I want columns to be NULL or NOT NULL.  It is the ANSI_NULLS option.

Comment: @Serg, it says to leave ANSI NULLS off too, hence my concern.   The application is our own developed in-house.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason is simple: backwards compatibility. For most current applications, it doesn't matter. All modern client libraries take care to provide their own defaults. For example, all ODBC and ADO.NET applications will specify `ANSI_NULLS` as `ON` by default. It's only the ancient apps that use something like the old `dblib` that will leave these settings up to the database, and precisely because they're so old, it's reasonable to expect they want the old behavior. This is why these options are still `OFF` by default even on modern versions of SQL Server, but they're mostly irrelevant.

Comment: If you are sure you have no old applications connecting, you can either choose to 1) shrug your shoulders and expect modern libraries to get the settings right anyway or 2) for maximum consistency even if a "bad" application happens to sneak up on you, set these options to sane defaults so everyone gets the same behavior. To be clear: this *only* applies to the ANSI settings; many other settings do not have natural defaults and represent true features where one way is not better than the other.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, that makes total sense and not something I had considered (modern client libs explicitly set these ANSI values on the connection making database defaults mostly irrelevant and ancient apps probably want the very old non-standard settings).  Great answers.  If you copy your two comments in as an answer and I'll mark it as so.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh: I took the liberty of doing a little more than that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are defaulting to `OFF` because, in all likelihood, this database was created and scripted without touching any of the defaults. When a database is created, it is essentially cloned from the `model` system database, and on a brand new install of SQL Server the ANSI settings on the database will be `OFF`, even though some of these settings (like `ANSI_NULLS`) are options you would really never want to be `OFF` for any modern database application. In fact, in the case of `ANSI_NULLS` in particular, the documentation specifies that the ability to turn it off at all is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188048), although it will likely still be a few years before that's really the case.

And therein lies the rub: these settings are still kept `OFF` for the benefit of old applications, who had to turn these options `ON` way back when to benefit from their goodness (and breaking changes). If the session specifies no values for them, the database settings are applied.

But most applications *do* specify these settings in a session, if not explicitly, then implicitly through their data access library. Per the documentation on [`SET ANSI_DEFAULTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188340), which toggles a bunch of settings at once:

> The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver and SQL Server Native Client
>   OLE DB Provider for SQL Server automatically set `ANSI_DEFAULTS` to `ON`
>   when connecting. The driver and Provider then set
>   `CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT` and `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` to `OFF`. The `OFF`
>   settings for `SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT` and `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`
>   can be configured in ODBC data sources, in ODBC connection attributes,
>   or in OLE DB connection properties that are set in the application
>   before connecting to SQL Server. The default for `SET ANSI_DEFAULTS` is
>   `OFF` for connections from DB-Library applications.

DB-Library is an old access library that is nevertheless still used by some ancient applications and optionally as a backing source for things like FreeTDS, so every so often you can still run into an application that deliberately or accidentally uses the database settings, but this is increasingly rare.

As to the *best* value for these options, that depends entirely on your use case. If you must support old applications that expect old behavior, you may have no choice in having to leave the database settings on `OFF`. If you have an application that connects through an old library but really expects modern SQL semantics, you may want to turn them `ON`. For all other applications, these options are likely already set on a per-session basis to their (in)correct values by the application itself and what you configure won't matter anyway.

A discussion on each individual option and when you'd want to turn it `ON` or `OFF` would exceed the limits of a reasonable answer. Consult the documentation on each of them and formulate your own best practices. You can let things like the [`SET` option requirements for indexes on computed columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189292) guide you, which require a bunch of options to be `ON` before you can even create them (and they're generally considered a nice thing to have).

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks